# String Array class in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need help with this code

Problem

1. Write a Java class having a String array, with global visibility.
2. Add a method that adds a given sting to the string array.
3. Add a method that searches for a given string in the string array.
4. Add a method that searches for a given character in the string array. The method should count and returns the occurrence of the given character.
5. Write an appropriate main method to test these class methods.

and this is the code. First,  I created a class for method I create scound class for TestString array

my question is i have error in scound class ,and i try to fix it but it dose not work
this the first class:

```
 /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package ooplab3;

    public class StringArray {

        String[] sTA = null;
        int index = 0; //last added sring position in the string array

        public StringArray() {
        }

        public String[] getsTA() {
            return sTA;
        }

        public String getsTAindex(int i) {
            return sTA[i];
        }

        public int getcounter() {
            return index;
        }

        public void setCounter(int counter) {
            this.index = counter;
        }

        public void addStrinToArray(String st) {
            if (this.index < sTA.length) {
                sTA[this.index] = st;
                this.index++;
            }
        }

        public int searchStringInArray(String sT) {
            int n = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.index; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    int indexOf = sTA[i].indexOf(sT);
                    n += searchStringInArray(sTA[i]);
                    return n;
                }
            }
            return n;
        }

        public int searchcharInArray(String sT) {
            int n = 0;
            int Startindex = 0;
            do {
                n += sT.indexOf(Startindex);
            } while (n > Startindex);
            return n;
        }

        public boolean containsChar(String s, char search) {
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return s.charAt(0) == search || containsChar(s.substring(1), search);
            }
        }

        public void containsChar(Object object, String search) {
        }


    }
```

Sound class :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ooplab3;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testStringarray {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String[] testArray = new String[30];
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input_txt"));


       // System.out.println("contents of testArray");

        int i = 0;
        while (infile.hasNext()) {
            String j = infile.next();
            addString(j, i);

            System.out.println(testArray[i] + "\n");

            i++;
        }
        }


    }


    the input file contain: hello this is my java program
```

Comment: What is the error in the second class?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a Java class having a String array, with global visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439448/write-a-java-class-having-a-string-array-with-global-visibility)

Comment: Possible duplicate of your own question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477545/qustion-in-string-array

Comment: this is the error run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented
contents of testArray
 at ooplab3.testStringarray.addString(testStringarray.java:32)
 at ooplab3.testStringarray.main(testStringarray.java:23)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, you have a class named `StringArray`, and a second class which is intended to test the capabilities of `StringArray`. But that second class doesn't actually *use* `StringArray` at all; instead, it creates its own array, and calls a method `addString()` which has a similar, but not identical, name as a method in `StringArray`.

One significant problem with `StringArray` is that it never creates an actual array -- its array member variable remains `null`. You need a "`new`" expression to create the actual array. Then your test class should be doing something like

```
StringArray sa = new StringArray();
sa.addStringToArray("Hello, world");
String[] array = sa.getsTA();
for (String s: array)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of problems exist.
Here's one of them:

In your StringArray.addStrinToArray() method, you attempt to assign a string to an element of a null array:

```
String[] sTA = null;
sTA[index] = st;  //this will throw NullPointerException
```

You need to initialise the array:

```
String[] sTA = new String[initialSize];
```

Where initialSize is an integer containing the initial size of the array.

Comment: this is what i gotrun:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented
contents of testArray
 at ooplab3.testStringarray.addString(testStringarray.java:32)
 at ooplab3.testStringarray.main(testStringarray.java:23)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: but how i can read from file  ?
becuse hello world is not in input file